# Is there any interesting description of $\Bbb Q_p^\times / \Bbb Q^\times$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Trying to reply to a comment to [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049844/96384), I realised I know no better description of the quotient of multiplicative groups $\Bbb Q_p^\times / \Bbb Q^\times$ than just that. Of course I am aware of
$$ \Bbb Q_p^\times \simeq p^\Bbb Z \times \mu_{p-1} \times (1+p\Bbb Z_p)$$
for odd $p$, the slight modification for $p=2$, and throwing the logarithm on the last factor, but that does not help a lot. The basic problem being that we mod out a non-closed subgroup.

Well I guess $\Bbb R^\times / \Bbb Q^\times$ or $\Bbb C^\times / \Bbb Q^\times$ are not that easy either, so what should one expect -- but maybe there is something surprising out there?

[This question and its answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1449204/96384) deal with the corresponding question for additive groups (and admit that there's not much nice to see there).

Comment: Looks hairy. Another analogue might be to look at the field of formal Laurent series $K((x))$ over a finite field $K$, where we have $K((x))^*=x^{\Bbb{Z}}\times K^*\times (1+x K[[x]])$, and try to get a handle on $K((x))^*/K(x)^*$. If anything, I would expect that to be a bit simpler. But I don't see anything natural there either. Effectively moding out the periodic series from $1+x K[[x]]$ doesn't feel inviting. I guess if we try to mod out a dense subgroup we deserve the headache we get.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen For $p=2$ I think the $2$-adic logarithm yields $\Bbb Q_2^\times/\Bbb Q^\times \cong (1+2 \Bbb Z_2) / (\prod_{q \text{ prime } \ge 3}' q^{\Bbb Z}) \cong 2 \Bbb Z_2  / (\sum_{q \text{ prime } \ge 3}' \log_2(q)\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Nice @reuns! I was thinking about something like that for moding out $\Bbb{Q}^*$, basically using that it is the free abelian group on primes. But the $\mu_{p-1}$ part seemed to make some modifications necessary. Except when $p=2$ as you pointed out.